# protected table with no prifix

Tags: laravel-8

I have a problem in the Models section

**protected $table = 'EMPLOYEE';**

All tables have a prifix (ESL_TableName) except EMPLOYEE how can I prevent this table from also being assigned Laravel's prifix.
Because currently all the SQL-statemnents are not correct

Can you help me there maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix on laravel, for example. You have ESL in every table name in your laravel application, you can setup table prefix in `config/database.php`,

```
'prefix' => 'ESL',
```

And yes it will prepend the prefix to the table, if you want to set `prefix` in your `.env` file you can:

```
...
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=ESL
...
```

and in `config/database.php`

```
'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX')
```

Comment: This is not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have a project where all database tables got a prefix. But now I have the problem that one database table (external from Laravel) has no prefix and I can't attach it to one. and I can't attach it to a prefix (there are other programs accessing this table). access this table).

When a query is performed on the data, the prefix is appended to the external table. This results in an error message, because of course this table does not exist.

Have also tried it with protected $table = 'employee' - Without success.

**Example:**

external table: employee

Query in Laravel: lim_employee

**Target:**

external table: employee

Query in Laravel: employee